# Flutter http post request no response

Tags: android, laravel, apache, flutter, http

I'm trying to make a post request from my flutter mobile application to a laravel api hosted on ionos.

The problem I encounter is that on some android smartphone, when the form is submitted, sometimes the progress loader load indefinitly without showing errors and sometimes it work imediately.

I have increased the alive time out int .htaccess file of my laravel app

```
<ifModule mod_env.c>
  SetEnv KeepAlive On
  SetEnv KeepAliveTimeout 100
  SetEnv MaxKeepAliveRequests 500
</ifModule>

<ifModule mod_headers.c>
  Header unset Connection
  Header set Connection keep-alive

  Header unset Keep-Alive
  Header set Keep-Alive timeout=100,max=500
</ifModule>
```

But the problem persist, it work successfully on some devices (most recent smartphones) and not on other sometimes.

Please help me, I'm facing the issue since 2 days

The flutter/dart code

```
sendHouse() async {
    String url = ServerConfigs.api_url + "/house";
    
    final Map<String, dynamic> house = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    house['name'] = name;
    house['img'] = image.path.split("/").last;
    List<int> imageBytes = image.readAsBytesSync();
    house['img64'] = Base64Codec().encode(imageBytes);
    house['lat'] = lat;
    house['lon'] = lon;
    
    final response = await http.post(url, headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + ServerConfigs.bearer_token
    }, body: {
      "data": house
    });

    var data = await json.decode(response.body);
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      emitSuccess();
    } else {
      print(data);
      print(response.statusCode);
      emitFailure();
    }
  }
```

Comment: Is there any error in `laravel.log` file? Can you also post flutter/dart code of how post is being made?

Comment: @Tpojka there are nothing in the laravel.log but I found in server logs the related requests with 413 error code, its look according to the file in the body data.

I've added the flutter/dart code

Comment: What is your `response status code` ?

Comment: @SaifulIslam the `response status code is 413`, I'm on a 1&1 shared hosting Apache server

Comment: If the response status code is 413 then the problem is from server side. take a loot on this link. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/413

Comment: @SaifulIslam thanks, I take a look on your link and the problem was the payload I sent size, I've added compress functionnaly in my dart code and it's solved.
thanks to you all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've added compress functionnaly to image in my dart code before upload and it solved.